# Return multiple values using JSON, jQuery and AJAX and Java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying multiple values ​​to return from my server to AJAX in Java. For now, I use this approach, but it's not a good solution:

**Javascript:**

```
success: function(list) {
    var firstValue = list[0];
    var secondValue = list[1];
    var thirdValue = list[2];
}
```

**Java:**

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
list.add(infoFirstValue());
list.add(infoThirdValue());
list.add(infoThirdValue());
String glist = gson.toJson(list);
response.getWriter().write(glist);
```

Is it possible to return several values ​​or an object or an other solution?

Comment: What is not good about this solution?

Comment: What part of the solution do you feel is not good? Is it a performance issue, or do you feel like your code needs improvement? Also, is it the Java code or the Javascript code that you'd like to improve?

Comment: Because it's not a dynamic code. If there is a new list. For example a list beetween infoFirstValue and infoThirdValue, My code JS should be amended.

Comment: GSON, which you're using, supports serializing Java objects into JSON objects. There's already an example on Stackoverflow of this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668862/good-json-java-library/1668951#1668951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it helps, here's some code snippets based on yours above, showing how to switch to an object-style response instead of an array. Gson includes the class `JsonObject` which might be the simplest thing for you to use: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html

However, Gson's way more powerful than that -- you can actually just serialize a plain old Java object directly, which is probably more elegant than the intermediate step of converting existing data to a `JsonObject` (see this existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668862/good-json-java-library/1668951#1668951). At the very least, the `info*Value()` methods would probably be better served as methods of an object you were serializing. And instead of storing the returned object properties as functionally-scoped variables in JavaScript, I presume you could just pass the object around and access its properties.

JAVA

```
JSONObject rv = new JSONObject();
rv.add("firstValue", infoFirstValue());
rv.add("secondValue", infoSecondValue());
rv.add("thirdValue", infoThirdValue());

String gobject = gson.toJson(rv);
response.getWriter().write(gobject);
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
success: function(obj){
  var firstValue = obj.firstValue;
  var secondValue = obj.secondValue;
  var thirdValue = obj.thirdValue;
}
```